# Python Multiprocessing - WinError 6 - The handle is invalid

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, multiprocessing, распараллеливание

Исключительно в целях самообразования пишу метод, занимающийся численными интегрированием, и делающий это распределенным образом.

Метод выглядит следующим образом:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def parallel_modified_simpson(x, y):
    procs = []
    queue = Queue()
    for j in range(1, len(x) - 1):
        p = Process(target=single_step_value,
                    args=(x[j - 1:j + 2], y[j - 1:j + 2], queue))
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)
    queue.put("DONE")
    value = queue_reader(queue)
    for p in procs:
        p.join()
    return value

def single_step_value(x, y, q):
    h1 = x[1] - x[0]
    h2 = x[2] - x[1]
    f0 = y[0]
    f1 = y[1]
    f2 = y[2]
    res = (h1 + h2)*(2*h1 - h2)/(6*h1) * f0 + \
          (h1 + h2)**3/(6*h1*h2) * f1 + \
          (h1 + h2)*(2*h2 - h1)/(6*h2) * f2
    q.put(res)

def queue_reader(q):
    val = 0.0
    while True:
        msg = q.get()
        if msg == "DONE":
            break
        val += msg
    retrun val

if __name__ == "__main__"
    # 
    # getting x and y from files
    # type(x) == list
    # type(y) == list
    #
    с = parallel_modified_simpson(x, y)
    #
    # further processing
    #
```

Во-первых, столкнулся с тем, что метод `single_step_value` не может быть внутри основного метода `parallel_modified_simpson`, что само по себе обидно.

А во-вторых, при попытке выполнения данного кода программа зависает, при прерывании по `Ctrl+C` выдает ошибку в модуле `multiprocessing\reduction.py`:

```
File "...\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 87, in steal_handle
    _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

Уважаемое сообщество, прошу помочь в решении данной проблемы!
Куда копать?

Comment: Добавьте вызывающий код, чтобы видеть, кто такие `x` и `y`.

Comment: @mkkik, x и y - простые списки (list), содержащие float. Ограничения на них: равная длина и наличие трёх или более элементов.

Comment: Так какого размера у вас эти списки? Пробовали на коротких данных запускать?

Comment: @mkkik списки и правда довольно большие, примерно по 3000 элементов. Проверил на коротких списках - ошибки нет. Отсюда вопрос - как изменить логику так, чтобы от длины не зависел результат?

Comment: Никак. В вашей искусственной задаче создается огромное число процессов (что довольно дорого), каждый из которых выполняет крайне простой код. Затраты на создание процесса и синхронизацию очереди значительно превосходят затраты на полезную работу. Если вы просто изучаете технологию, сформулируйте более подходящую задачу приближенную к реальности.

Comment: @mkkik Могут ли мне помочь Pool и Semaphore? Да, безусловно, просто изучаю технологию, я вроде как об этом упомянул :-) В любом случае, спасибо за потраченное время!

Comment: Посмотрите примеры в документации к библиотеке, там довольно хорошо показано, как применять эти инструменты.

Answer (score 1):

метод `single_step_value` не может быть вложенным, так как он запускается в отдельном процессе, а значит он должен быть обособленным и не может к примеру менять глобальные переменные. Вы запускаете множество процессов без контроля их кол-ва не смотря на использование класса очереди. Чтобы ваш код не зависел от кол-ва элементов в `x` вам нужно использовать пул процессов. К тому же попытка запустить дочерних процессов больше чем кол-во ядер (хотя иногда имеет смысл сделать по 2 процесса на процессор) кончается тем, что вы получите деградацию скорости работы всей программы. Почти та же ситуация и с потоками.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


def child_process(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)


with Pool() as pool:
    # пул будет запускать кол-во дочерних процессов равное кол-ву процессоров.
    pool.map_async(child_process, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

Comment: Спасибо! А что в случае, если `child_process` должен возвращать результат?

Comment: Тогда нужно использовать метод .map(), он вернет список с результатами в том же порядке что и переданный список аргументов.

Answer (score 0):

С помощью уважаемого сообщества удалось решить поставленную задачу, избавиться от описанной в тексте вопроса ошибки.

Безусловно, сама задача исключительно учебная и время, затрачиваемое на выполнение параллельной реализации, на два порядка превосходит время, затрачиваемое на выполнение однопоточной реализации (интегрируемая зависимость описывается 3000 парами точек {x, y}).

Ниже привожу код для версии `python 3.7` с добавлением явного указания типов для удобства:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from itertools import repeat
from typing import List

Vector = List[float]
PQueue = mp.Queue


def parallel_modified_simpson(x: Vector, y: Vector) -> float:
    def queue_reader(q: PQueue) -> float:
        val = 0.0
        while True:
            elem = q.get()
            if not elem:
                break
            val += elem
        return val

    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        manager = mp.Manager()
        queue = manager.Queue()
        x_args = tuple(x[j - 1:j + 1] for j in range(1, len(x) - 1))
        y_args = tuple(y[j - 1:j + 1] for j in range(1, len(y) - 1))
        args = list(zip(x_args, y_args, repeat(queue)))
        workers = pool.starmap_async(single_step_value, args)
        workers.wait()
        queue.put(None)
    value = queue_reader(queue)
    return value


def single_step_value(x: Vector, y: Vector, q: PQueue) -> None:
    value = 0.0
    h1 = x[1] - x[0]
    h2 = x[2] - x[1]
    f0 = y[0]
    f1 = y[1]
    f2 = y[2]
    value += (h1 + h2)*(2*h1 - h2)/(6*h1) * f0 + \
             (h1 + h2)**3/(6*h1*h2) * f1 + \
             (h1 + h2)*(2*h2 - h1)/(6*h2) * f2
    q.put(value)
```